# Problem with using OVER() with the function AVG() in mySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a table F01 in my localhost server containing 3 columns: ID, value and hour.
I need to average the values using the 4 preceding values for example. So I wrote the following line:

```
SELECT hour, value, AVG(value) OVER (order by hour rows between 4 preceding and current row) from F01;
```

It's working fine locally.
However, I have the exact same table in a server and when I type the same command, it says :

#1064 - Erreur de syntaxe près de '(order by time rows between 4 preceding and current row) from F01 LIMIT 0, 25' à la ligne 1.

Now, if I remove the part OVER(), it's working fine. But it only gives me the average of the column. Is there a problem using OVER with AVG in certain situations?

The version of my localhost is:

Apache/2.4.43 (Win64) OpenSSL/1.1.1g PHP/7.4.8

Version of the database : libmysql - mysqlnd 7.4.8

Version of PHP : 7.4.8

The version of the server is :

Apache/2.4.25 (Debian)

Version of the database : libmysql - mysqlnd 5.0.12-dev - 20150407

Version de PHP : 7.0.33-0+deb9u10

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using on the server? Window functions were added in 8.0.

Comment: It could be that. It says mysqlnd 5.0.12-dev - 20150407.

Comment: That's the PHP library, not the server version.

Comment: Oh sorry. It is 10.1.47-MariaDB-0+deb9u1 - Debian 9.13.

Comment: Window functions were added in MariaDB 10.2.0.

Comment: There we go. The version on my localhost is 10.4.13-MariaDB. Must be that. I'm going to contact the guy in charge of the server and ask him to update it. Thank you so much for your help!